# Gatsby CLI npm package installing is not working

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, gatsby

Trying to install gatsby CLI globally on MacBook M1.

Tried with the below command using terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

It is always showing the below error in the terminal.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/gulp-cli - Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'gulp-cli@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kelumchathuranga/.npm/_logs/2021-03-23T10_12_52_463Z-debug.log
```

**Development environment details:**

MacBook Pro M1

Node version: v14.16.0

NPM version: 7.6.3

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jky1p.jpg)

Please anyone can help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried without `sudo`?

Comment: @FerranBuireuYes I have tried with `sudo`. But it is not working

Comment: Does it help? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4967#issuecomment-461679825